# ASUS K501UX (4K): Is there space for a second hard drive?

Tags: hard-drive, asus-laptop

I recently bought an ASUS K501UX and thought the 250GB SSD was a little too small. I wanted to buy a large HDD and use it as a secondary drive, but I wasn't sure if there was space. I looked it up, but I only found reviews and information about an older version of the K501UX. I could not find anything about the newer model with a 4K screen, only the old one. Here's a link to the model that I bought http://www.costco.com/ASUS-K501UX-Laptop---Intel-Core-i7---4K-Ultra-HD---2GB-Graphics.product.100230346.html

Comment: From what I can gather, the SSD that's in it is an M.2 style SSD.  It looks like other models of that laptop have regular hard drives instead.  Perhaps there is a SATA connection on the motherboard, but the only way to know for sure is to open it up.

Comment: @TimmyJim I tried opening it, but I busted one of the screws. I was going to take it to a PC repair shop, but if there wasn't space for a second drive I thought it wouldn't be worth going

Comment: Have you considered an external drive?

Comment: @TimmyJim I haven't thought about that actually. I'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

I watched a video that showed opening the machine. The HD plugs directly into the mother board. There is no space for a second drive. The only option is to get a larger HD.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you provided a link to the video.

Answer (score 0):

"It depends" - I found an unofficial 'service manual' for [this model online](https://cukusa.com/service-manuals/asus-k501ux-ah71.html) from a vendor which sells parts. It suggests opening it is a *little* involved - but that there's both a sata m.2 bay and a single hard disk bay inside the unit. Depending on what the system ships with (250gb's a really common SSD size), you should be able to use the other slot to add storage.